# Better way to reload a tableview after iterating over an image array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Right now the tableview is being reloaded in a completion block after the image data is updated. This problem with this is that it appears to reload after EVERY single individual image is updated causing weird behavior like flickering and rapidly changing images. Here is the code:

```
      var knownForArray: [UIImage] = []
      var knownForExtendedArray: [CastExtendedData] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
 CastExtendedData.updateAllData(urlExtension: "\(personID)/movie_credits", completionHandler: {results in
    self.knownForData = results
    if let knownFor = self.knownForData?.castExtended {
      self.knownForExtendedArray = knownFor
      for knownForImage in knownFor {
        if let poster = knownForImage.poster {
          self.updateImage(ImageType: DownloadPic.knownFor, ImageString: poster, completion: {_ in //This is the completion block where the tableview is reloaded
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.knownForTableView.reloadData()
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })




 func updateImage (ImageType: DownloadPic, ImageString: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

   self.networkManager.downloadImage(imageExtension: "\(ImageString)", { (imageData) in
          if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data) {
        switch ImageType { //Was more case statements but edited out to make question more concise
            case DownloadPic.knownFor: if let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data){self.knownForArray.append(image)}
              break
            }
          }
          completion()
        })
      }
```

This is the CellForRowAtIndexPath, it's connected to a tableview cell that has an embedded CollectionView on it:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = knownForTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: knownForCellIdentifier) as! KnownForCell

        cell.imageDelegete = self
        cell.knownForExtendedArray = self.knownForExtendedArray
        cell.knownForArray = self.knownForArray
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          cell.knownForCollectionView.reloadData()
        }

        return cell
}
```

This is the tableviewCell with the collectionView:

```
  var knownForArray: [UIImage] = []
  var knownForExtendedArray: [CastExtendedData] = []

extension KnownForCell:  UICollectionViewDelegate {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return knownForArray.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = knownForCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: knownForReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! KnownForCollectionViewCell

      if let knownPoster = self.knownForExtendedArray[indexPath.row].poster{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.knownForImages.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)\(knownPoster)"))//This is a cocoapod used to download images async (SDWebImage)
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Load images on another thread. whenever the images completes its downloading just set the image to that cell's imageview. But First of all create all the cell with those imageviews

Comment: In this way you don't have to reload the tableview everytime

Comment: I thought I was using the main thread to load the images already

Comment: Only update UI on main thread. load images on background thread

Comment: How would you load images on another thread, is it like   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.updateImage
            }

Comment: Though on completion you are calling tableview.reloaddata but that is not feasible. post you cellForRowAt code in there. So I would give you the exact code what you should do

Comment: So your `downloadImage ` get called multiple times that lead to the loop of reloadTable? If you have number of images to download, just make an int to count the numbers of images downloaded and call code by that

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question to include the cellForRowAtIndexPath and TableViewCell

Comment: Do you know the count of images that are going to be downloaded? to pass in numberOfItemsInSections

Comment: I don't, it's random based on what the user chooses