# How to call a function after a loop has ended?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, loops, tableview

Currently we have part of a function where after JSON data has be collected and assigned to a data object. We then loop through the data object's image data value to update the imageviews. After the loop is finished we reload the tableview.  The problem that is occurring is the tableview is reloading after EVERY single object is updated creating flashing and other visual miscues.  If the tableview can load after ALL the image data has been updated it would be better.  Here is that portion of the code:

```
  if let extraImages = self.profileData?.images{

    let extraMovieImages = extraImages.images
    for image in extraMovieImages {
      self.updateImage(ImageType: DownloadPic.personal, ImageString: image.filePath, completion: {_ in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.TableView.reloadData()
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't this a repost of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084587/better-way-to-reload-a-tableview-after-iterating-over-an-image-array)?

Comment: I asked something similar with none of the answers working so I simplified the question

Comment: I closed your previous question as a duplicate. The duplicate showed you what you needed to do. And it's the answer being provided below by JuicyFruit.

Comment: why not place the `async` call after the `for` loop?

Comment: @muescha There are more details in the OP's previous question. The important detail left out of this repost is that `self.updateImage` is an async network call.

Comment: @maddy thanks for info - without full information it is impossible to give the right answer

Comment: then i would recommend a library where the image loading and displaying the image is done by the special image view and you don't need to do it manually.

Comment: maybe this frameworks are for this use case: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `DispatchGroup`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
for image in extraMovieImages {
    group.enter()
    self.updateImage(ImageType: DownloadPic.personal, ImageString: image.filePath, completion: {_ in
        group.leave()
    })
}
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
     self.TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make a variable before the loop:

```
let expectedCount = extraMovieImages.count
```

Then count it down in the completion block and when it gets to 0, reload.

Another idea is if you know which row each image is on, just reload that row, not the whole table.

Comment: This is good too but the count isn't the same for each object